# XSL: for each within another for each iterating data

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to perform a cyclical sequence within another public secuanci and get the data of each person and each status, the problem that I have with the code is that it does not iterate the data that I am delivering. I need help in the second for-each when I have empty fields and then I can work with Word content controls

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<emailList>
  <person>
    <name>name 1</name>
    <email>g@gmail.com</email>
    <status>
        <active>1</active>
        <active>2</active>
        <active>3</active>
    </status>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>name 2</name>
    <email>n@hotmail.com</email>
    <status>
        <active>4</active>
        <active>5</active>
    </status>
  </person>
</emailList>
```

XSL file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="1.0">
  <head>
    <title>Email Listing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>E-mail Address</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="emailList/person">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td>
          <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="emailList/person/status">
            <xsl:value-of select="active"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You inner `xsl:for-each` will be relative to the outer one, which is selecting `person`.

Try changing it to this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="status/active">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Where `.` selects the current node.

If you wanted to separate the values by commas, you could do this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="status/active">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Better still, upgrade to XSLT 2.0 and do away with this `xsl:for-each` entirely..

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="status/active" separator="," />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Email Listing</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>E-mail Address</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="emailList/person">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="status">
                                <xsl:value-of select="active"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
```